# New to VLAN configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vlan

I have a network using an M4100 switch connected to an EdgeRouter Infinity. I'm also connecting to the EdgeRouter over PPTP for configuration and testing purposes.

I've created VLAN 80 on the M4100 and tagged the uplink port for VLAN 80. The uplink port goes directly to eth0 on the EdgeRouter and has firewall rules set for providing DHCP/DNS. The services are working perfectly and the M4100 is able to receive an address and resolve forwarded DNS from the EdgeRouter.

The problem I'm having is that when I add VLAN 80 as a sub-interface to eth0 I immediately lose contact with the M4100 until the VLAN is disabled. I've tried applying an IP to the VLAN interface itself (both being the same as the physical interface, another subnet, as well as just leaving the virtual IF subnet undefined) but the result is the same.

Comment: A tagged VLAN requires that both sides of the link are sending and receiving VLAN tags with the same VLAN ID. Can you change eth0 to use VLAN 80 without tagging? In response to your question, what you might be doing wrong is starting to make configuration changes without having studied and fully understanding how VLANs work. My suggestion is you hit the books/web.

Comment: Some devices just don't support tagged and untagged traffic on the same port; So my first try would be to tag the base port traffic as well - but I don't know the Device you quote, so this is pure debugging. Remember that both devices need to know the VLANs.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Do you mean setting the M4100 uplink port to untagged? Wouldn't this prevent the traffic headed back to the router from being placed in VLAN 80? Your assessment is a fair one though I often find experimentation in a controlled environment more educational than studying raw data.

Comment: @Dualed If by base port traffic you mean the native VLAN, then yes, I've tried tagging it along with VLAN 80. Then I went to the router and configured a sub-interface for both but I then had a worse problem where I couldn't get to the M4100 management UI and had to switch to another port to undo it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written "base interface", port was ambiguous, I'd strongly suggest connecting through a different physical interface for management of the edge router, that will make debugging significantly easier, but apart from that it's a bit hard to tell, maybe a more detailed description will help, or maybe it is just device specific behaviour.

Comment: Also, having recently spent many hours fixing a botched vlan config of a colleague, I'm kinda with @toddwilcox - learn and plan before you act

Comment: @Dualed Haha, I agree but unfortunately there is only 1 available interface so the testing is a little annoying.

Comment: I'm saying that if you are applying VLAN tags to frames for egress from a port, then the receiving port has to be configured to expect those VLAN tags on the frames it receives, and the VLAN IDs have to match. You can't configure VLAN tagging on only one side of a link, you must configure both sides. The phrase "tagged the uplink port for VLAN 80" concerns me because it reflects a misunderstanding of how it all works. You don't tag ports. Tags are applied to frames. If I understand what you've written in your question correctly, you're way off base and need to get a grip on how this works.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Its my understanding that assigning tagging for a port determines whether the frames that pass through it are tagged on the egress. Also, I believe that by creating VLAN 80 on the router's physical interface that's connected to the switch, I'm also creating a connection between the 2 devices using VLAN 80. The whole purpose of me asking questions is actually to get a grip on how it works...

Comment: There's too large a gap between your current understanding and making this connection work for a reasonable Stack Exchange answer to fill the entire gap. You should be able to make several tests to see if VLAN 80 is actually listed as up and linked on each device. Each device will have its own "nomenclature" for how to make it send and receive tagged frames. For example, on some devices, creating a subinterface will make the device transmit and receive VLAN tags on that physical port for the VLAN ID related to the subinterface, but not all devices will work the same way.

Comment: There are also some parts of the question that are unclear. When you say you "lose contact", between what and what? You have a management computer that is connected to the devices for making configuration changes? How is it connected? Serial console? Telnet/SSH? How are you establishing that connection? Are you connecting over the same ports that you are using to test VLAN configurations? If so, you should expect to be disconnected? What IP addresses are you configuring on these subinterfaces/virtual interfaces, if any?

Comment: In short, there's a lot about this question that doesn't really make sense, and that seems to be because there's too much about what you're doing that you're not prepared to do or ask about. If you're able to figure out how to configure working VLANs just through experimentation, then you're either very lucky or a complete genius. Most of us read extensively either in books or online to understand how all this works, and/or we watch training videos and/or have someone show us in person. Training is not really what Stack Exchange is about.

Comment: Can you post the M4100 configuration?  If you have set the uplink port to tag Vl80, then it shouldn't work *until* you configure the subinterface.  The fact that it does (did), means the switch isn't configured the way you think it is.

Comment: I went over to the test setup and plugged into the switch. It appeared to be doing what I expected of it as I had Internet while plugged in but I wasn't able to access the management UI. I figured it was because I didn't change the management VLAN and I ended up getting into the console to use the CLI and updated the management to VLAN 80. Still couldn't get in though so maybe I was missing something. I ended up powercycling it to dump the config and got the UI back. Anyway, here's the [config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nH42Mum8ICzZCqkqjG7NngL_gqxHkehz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SilentOne I don't see where you're tagging vl 80 on the trunk (int 0/49)

Comment: @Ron Trunk Funny you should say that. Port 49 is designated as a trunk port and the switch refuses to allow me to change the tagging on it while the uplink is connected. It does however show a T under VLAN 80 for port 49 so my (possibly false) expectation here is that it is tagged. Do you think the fact that the port 49 is a combo port on this switch has any bearing?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it sorted out. The first problem I had was that by defining the uplink as a trunk port I was preventing myself from being able to customize the configuration and this is why couldn't untag the trunk port. If you set a port to trunk the Netgear automatically sets the VLANs as tagged for that port. I feel it's actually better to use the VTP section of the switch to define which VLANs are allowed across a trunk port and leave the port itself set to General mode.

Secondly, the trunking problem wasn't entirely a VLAN problem, it was a firewall problem too. I defined a separate set of rules for each virtual interface and am now getting the behavior I expected.